# Want to extend empty interface but getting lint error: no-empty-interface

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, lint

Today, I tried to do this in my angular 6 application:

```
export interface AuthConfig {}

export interface BasicAuthConfig extends AuthConfig {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}

export interface OAuth2AuthConfig extends AuthConfig {
    tokenName: string;
    url: string;
    callbackUrl: string;
    clientId: string;
    scope: string[];
    grantType: grantTypes;
}
```

And got a lint error:

```
An empty interface is equivalent to `{}`. (no-empty-interface)
```

I wanted to do this with my Endpoint interface:

```
Export interface Endpoint {
…
authConfig: AuthConfig;
…
}
```

But was reduced to doing this:

```
Export interface Endpoint {
…
authConfig: BasicAuthConfig | OAuth2AuthConfig;
…
}
```

The different types of authorization could get lengthy so I don’t want to keep tacking on the types to the authConfig property of the Endpoint interface. Is there any way to declare an empty interface for the purpose of extending it without lint yelling at me?

Thanks.

Comment: This could also be done by exporting a type and setting it to either `BasicAuthConfig` or `OAuth2AuthConfig`. (Example: `export type AuthConfig = BasicAuthConfig | OAuth2AuthConfig`)

Answer (score 23):

You can either disable this rule in `tslint.json`:

```
"rules": { "no-empty-interface": false }
```

Or just disable linting for one line:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line
export interface AuthConfig {}
```

Comment: Or use `// tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface` to _only_ disable the `no-empty-interface` rule.

Comment: The reason this rule exists is that typescript uses structural typing, so defining an empty interface does not help differentiate two types. I would heed the warning and avoid empty interfaces

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir It makes change much easier to manage though.

Answer (score 14):

### How to disable

```js
Example:
$ cat .eslintrc.js
  ...
  "rules": {
  '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface': 'off'
  }
  ...
```

Comment: in the case of using eslint and typescript at the same time, your answer will work nicly. thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
export interface AuthConfig {}
```

Comment: The really proper way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is use `type` instead of `interface` like `export type AuthConfig = {};` since in typescript 2.2 it is possible to extend `type` too

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
type AuthConfig = Record<string, never>
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a possible solution I finally found you can use `type AuthConfig = Record<never, never>`. By using `Record<string, never>`, as many suggest, you create a paradox where any string that comes in expects to return never... only to try and overwrite that behavior. By using `Record<never, never>`, we expect access using type `never` to return `never`. This way we can override what happens when we pass in a string and expect to get a different type (like username and password)